# Почему не работает функция с замыканием?

Tags: javascript

Написать функцию, которая принимает 1 параметр. При первом вызове, она его запоминает, при втором — суммирует переданный параметр с тем, что передали первый раз и тд. Всё это с замыканиями, например: sum(3) = 3 sum(5) = 8 sum(20) = 28

```js
function getParam() {
 let num = prompt("Введите число ");
 let sum = 0;
 
 return function resultSum() {
  return sum += num;
 };

}

let result = getParam();
```

Comment: `let num = +prompt("Введите число ");` поправьте так. А так у Вас все работает. И тут поменяйте `function resultSum(val) { sum+=val`

Comment: возвращает только фунцию resultSum,а не результат

Comment: `let result = getParam(); console.log('sum+10: '+result(10)); console.log('sum+15: '+result(15));`

Comment: Каждый раз когда фунция должна вызыватся,то она сама должна прибавлять число и выводить уже новое число. А так она выводит только то число которое указанно в параметрах

Comment: То есть когда пишу в консоль result, каждый раз должна срабатывать эта фунция. А она возвращает только саму функцию resultSum

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getParam() {
 let num = +prompt("Введите число ");
 let sum = 0;
 
 return function resultSum() {
  return sum += num;
 };

}

let result = getParam();
console.log(result());
```